# Tips to confirm JMeter script is working when receiving no errors

Tags: jmeter

I am running a JMeter script to hit a web page that opens another link to a shopping cart.  There are a few different urls that JMeter recorded for me using the HTTP Script Recorder.  When running the JMeter script, I receive no errors in any logs ( JMeter log and a few summary report / View results tree logs ).  I even added a Constant Timer to some of the pages that do actually take a few seconds to load when hitting them manually in a web browser.  In the end, I cannot see what is happening, but JMeter also does not indicate any errors.  How can I confirm that each url hit is actually succeeding so that the shopping cart actually gives me my item when JMeter is done?

Comment: So far, a good tool I have been using is the View Results Tree to see what responses I have been receiving along with the network traffic.  I was hoping to find something a little more like Selenium in which I could see something happening or some other indication that my parameters were correct / incorrect.  "200" http response codes back every time only indicates that the success of the web page, but not success for adding the item to the shopping cart.  I am looking for something more than just the "200" success http response codes back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If JMeter is able to make a http request successfully, it will be always green in View Results Tree (200 http code). It does not mean that your test is correct - ie even if the login is not successful JMeter does not report it as error/failure unless you validate the response.

I think you need assertions to ensure that the http response you get is as you are expecting.

[image]

[image]